# Filter/Sort through a value with three associated values (MONTH, DAY, and YEAR)

Tags: php

I'm trying to filter through some images.

Each image has 3 sets of values that I need to sort through collectively, MONTH, DAY, YEAR.

I'm trying to figure out how to choose a specific a YEAR, DAY, **and/or** MONTH and then filter my list of images accordingly.

This isn't homework. I don't study CS. I'm writing this in PHP, but your answer probably doesn't need php code for me to know what to do.

I don't know that much about sorting algorithms. Perhaps someone could also point me to an interesting introduction to this topic as well?

Just to make things more clear:

I'd like to be able to go through it backwards or forwards, for example, if someone only selects one of the filters/values, like DAY, then the images displayed will be all those associated with that DAY, regardless of MONTH or YEAR.

I have everything already written. It is a website with drop down menus, and when a user selects one item from the YEAR, DAY, or MONTH menus, I will repopulate the others accordingly.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How are the images stored? This would seem like a simple db query.

Comment: if you have the data in a database, a simple SQL query would do the trick.

Comment: Actually I just drop them in a directory. - Each image has a filename with these values separated by dashes, and I just break up the filenames to populate my arrays. So the script will actually be filtering which files to load from a directory. - I guess in that sense, I can't use any DB related commands.

Comment: what have you written so far? are you looping through the files? storing any info?

Comment: Yes. I separate the string of each file into an array. [YEAR, MONTH, DAY, filename]. I want to decide whether to add these arrays into a multidimensional array. This larger array will be the selected images.

Comment: I think I found it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's `usort`  with a custom comparison callback function.